# Cant get pyperclip to use copy and paste modules on python3

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Specs:

- Python3.5
- Latest Pyperclip
- Both xclip and python3-pyqt4 installed
- using ssh(Putty) to connect to headleass raspberry pi 2 model B using Latest Raspian Stretch Light

---

```
Error: pyperclip.copy('Hello world!')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 612, in lazy_load_stub_copy
    return copy(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 297, in __call__
    raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
pyperclip.PyperclipException:
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error
```

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling both the module and clipboard programs. ive searched for 2 hours looking for an answer and used all of them and they didn't work. I admit i am a noob but it SHOULD'NT be this hard for me to do this.

Comment: Have you set things up to, e.g., tunnel X11 through ssh to an X server on your desktop?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to _do_ with the clipboard? On a headless system, there's nothing to copy from or paste into.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The clipboard is part of your GUI. But you don't *have* a GUI. So there is no clipboard to copy and paste with. There is no clipboard for pyperclip to access, so it doesn't matter how you try to access it, you're going to fail.

You can test very easily by running this at the shell:

```
xclip
```

If it says something like `Error: No display: (null)`, then that's your problem.

---

If you *think* you should have a GUI, because you've set things up to, e.g., tunnel X11 through ssh to an X server on your desktop machine, but you're still getting an error from `xclip`, then the problem is that you've set things up wrong. The simplest thing to check is:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

Is that empty? Then your session doesn't know anything about your X11 tunnel. Getting tunneling set up properly is really an issue for a site like Super User or Unix, not Stack Overflow—and, once you get that fixed, `pyperclip`, and your script, should just start working.

---

As for what you can do about it… well, it depends on why you were trying to use `pyperclip` in the first place. On a headless system, there's nowhere to copy data from, and nowhere to paste it to, so it wouldn't be particularly useful.

If you're trying to, e.g., share data between two different Python scripts on the same machine, then there are simpler ways to do that than passing it through a clipboard—just use a file, a pipe, a socket, etc.—that don't even require a third-party library with complicated setup.

Comment: its the very latest version of the light os when i echo display it gives me a blank line, but im currently download the latest full os for raspian and will get back to you when i test it. also i dont expect there to be a gui cause  inever set one up .

Comment: @MatthewMankiewicz I don't know what the first half of that is about or why it's relevant. But if you don't have a GUI, then what are you expecting to do with the clipboard? As-is, what you're asking to do just doesn't make sense. But I'm sure you're trying to do something that makes perfect sense, and if you can explain what it is, we can probably tell you a way to accomplish it.

Comment: im just using the raspberry pi as a python programming enviroment. i was gonna use pyperclip to copy the msg hello world then use pyperclip to paste it into the cmd line

Comment: @MatthewMankiewicz What you paste into the command line with Cttl-V or whatever doesn’t come from the rpi’s clipboard, it comes from your Windows clipboard through Putty. There’s no way code running on the rpi can affect that.

Comment: i mean i want to use pyperclip.copy("Hello World") within the pi and paste it in the pi. Because the pi is supposed to copy the msg that its set to copy and paste it into the cmd line. BUt ive already established that the missing gui is probably the issue here. thanks for your responses though!

Comment: also i just conencted the pi to a moniter and did it manually and it stil lsays same error

Comment: @MatthewMankiewicz When you connected it to a monitor, are you running a text framebuffer, or are you running an X11 GUI?

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Run this command on your terminal, then run the Python test.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved by installing one of the recommended utility, read the [Pyperclip’s documentation](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#not-implemented-error). So, depending on your system, it could be:
`sudo apt-get install xclip`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having the same problem on my first Raspberry Pi. Try running `sudo apt-get install xsel`. You can read about what this does [here](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/), but essentially it's a clipboard utility that Pyperclip can use.

If this doesn't work it probably has something to do with the fact that you're trying to do this over SSH, but that shouldn't necessarily be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You may get an error message that says: “Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system. Please see https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error for how to fix this.”

In order to work equally well on Windows, Mac, and Linux, Pyperclip uses various mechanisms to do this. Currently, this error should only appear on Linux (not Windows or Mac). You can fix this by installing one of the copy/paste mechanisms:

- `sudo apt-get install xsel` to install the xsel utility.
- `sudo apt-get install xclip` to install the xclip utility.