# pyperclip module raising an error message

Tags: python, archlinux, pyperclip

I'm using Python 3.4.0 on ArchLinux (**without X11**) as guest in a Vagrant box. When running my script I get this error message:

> Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system

According to this [link](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error), I've installed **xsel** and **xclip** packages but I cannot install **gtk** nor **PyQt4** modules, because I get this another error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from
>   versions: )

According to this [post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=236955), I should install **python3-pyqt4** package, but the package more near showed by pacman is **python-pyqt5** and it requires to install many packages included packages for X11. Is this necessary? I wish to preserve my distro light as possible.

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explanation about this problem and why it won't work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662213/cant-get-pyperclip-to-use-copy-and-paste-modules-on-python3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method fixed it for me.

`pip install QtPy`

also you could refer to this thread for more help
https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error