# (python) Github Actions test selenium copy paste

Tags: python, django, selenium, github-actions

I am testing my python application with e2e tests and use github actions as part of my CI. Normal selenium tests work totally fine. I added a click to copy functionality and want to test it via a unit test. So far I am using pyperclip to do this:

```
import pyperclip
link = pyperclip.paste()
assert link == "target link"
```

Locally on my machine (OSX) everything works fine. Unfortunately, I am not able to get this library working with ubuntu on github actions. I get this error:

```
Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system. Please see https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error for how to fix this.
```

I've checked the page but I am not able to get it working. Does someone know a way how to access the clipboard in github actions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below `run` command before running the tests

```
- name: Install xsel
  run: sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Please find reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662213/cant-get-pyperclip-to-use-copy-and-paste-modules-on-python3)